# Is it typical for a java.lang.Error to be thrown outside the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html),

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch.

I am using a library which catches and ignores all `Throwable`s in user callbacks. I am wondering if I should add a catch block for all `Throwable`s in other threads in order to log those failures. I want to avoid the case where worker threads die silently yet the main thread continues. Is this a scenario I should be concerned about?

Comment: Why don't you register an uncaught exception handler?

Comment: @shmosel I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's rather vague.

Comment: It turns out the library is ignoring all exceptions like `try { handler.callback(); } catch (Throwable t) {}`, so my UncaughtExceptionHandler is never called.

Comment: So how do you plan on handling them if they're suppressed internally?

Comment: Please add some example code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I can handle java.lang.Error in my callbacks. Program termination due to java.lang.Error being thrown in the main thread is acceptable, but I want to avoid the situation where java.lang.Error occurs in worker threads yet the main thread survives. Is it typical for a java.lang.Error to be thrown outside the main thread? If it never happens, there is no code needed to address it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a library which catches and ignores all Throwables in user callbacks.

@shmosel's commentary is pointing in correct direction:

> Why don't you register an uncaught exception handler?

Of course, you can not achieve anything by simply registering a custom uncaught exception handler — the exceptions won't reach it because the poorly-written library is swallowing them!

To solve that problem you should rewrite each of those "user callbacks": wrap the callback code in try-catch and pass the received Throwable to the uncaught exception handler:

```
try {
    // the code of your callback goes here
    ...
} catch (Throwable error) {
    // if you don't control individual Threads, consider using a
    // Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler instead
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();

    thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(thread, error);
}
```

Ideally this should have been done by the library, that invokes your callbacks, — using Thread's global exception handler for unexpected exceptions from user code is a common pattern, frequently used by Executors and application servers.

In meantime, contact the third-party library and suggest it's developers to fix that issue — silently swallowing exceptions is definitely a bad idea!